# How to replace multiple substrings in a long string, while continuously updating indices

Tags: python, text, nlp

Lets say I have a fixed string such as:

`"Jacob went to the park to play"`

And, I put this string through a BERT NER model to identify entities; for the sake of argument, lets assume that the model only returned "Jacob" as a person, but decomposed it into several subwords, so the NER output would be something like:

`ents = [{'word_piece':'##Ja'','start'0:,'end'2:,'tag':'B-PER'},{'word_piece':'##co'','start'2:,'end'4:,'tag':'B-PER'}, {'word_piece':'##b'','start'4:,'end'5:,'tag':'I-PER'}]`

(this isn't the actual format, but contains all the information necessary. Lets say that **all** entities have a char length of 5 i.e. I-PER, B-PER, I-ORG etc.

I want to put the tokens back into the string, so it would be something like this:

`"B-PER B-PER I-PER went to the park to play"`

I.e. I want to loop through each entity, then update the string, and the string indices.

I have tried looping through each example, adding 7 (as all entities are = 5 + spaces on either side) * number of times an element has been replaced + len(word_piece.replace(##))...

```
i = 0
for eg in ents:
   start = i*7 + eg['start']
   end = i*7 + eg['end'] + len(eg['start']-eg['end'])
   stem = sent[:start]
   tail = sent[end:]
   sent = stem + ' ' + eg['tag'] + ' ' + tail
   i += 1
```

But I still cannot seem to get it right. The offsets begin to accumulate and lead to a jumble.